# Widget with more than one layout

Tags: android, widget

I want to create a widget that I can move between layouts in a click of a button, but I didnt figure out how to do it, I tried to update the widget manager in onReceive when I click on a button but it didnt work

I saw that in the "Eye in the sky" (a weather) widget they are doing so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create 2 layouts in xml.  Then when the button is clicked, create a new instance of the widget and inflate it with the alternate xml layout, attaching it to the parent window.  Then update your internal reference of the widget to this new widget as well.